# How can I integrate ion_auth library with CodeIgniter 3 HMVC on Linux?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, ion-auth

I am coding a base application using codeigniter, hmvc and ion_auth. I have loaded ion_auth in application/modules/Users. Everything works on my windows development PC, but I am getting an error on my hosting server (linux) when the application starts:

```
  Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Ion_auth_model
```

In the modules/Users/library/Ion_auth.php, I try to load the model as follows:

```
  $this->load->model('Users/Ion_auth_model', 'ion_auth_model');
```

The model file is in modules/Users/models/Ion_auth_model.php.

I have tried many different combinations of file names. I know Linux is case sensitive. Any suggestions? Am I missing something simple?

Comment: So, as a sanity check, I moved the Ion_auth_model.php file into application/models and changed the load function to the standard way of loading the model. It seems to work, but why does it not work when in the Users directory since I am using hmvc?

Answer (score 0):

At first,  your folder names must be started with lowercase character.
....... keep Ion Auth in its own module folder... your modules folder must look like:

```
   
 modules
   ∟ home
   ∟ admin
   ∟ auth
      ∟ controllers
      ∟ models
      ∟ views
      ∟ libraries
      ∟ config
      ∟ language
```